# Opening pdf documents in SharePoint 2010

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I force SharePoint 2010 to open PDF's in the browser?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/how-can-i-force-sharepoint-2010-to-open-pdfs-in-the-browser)

Is there a way in SharePoint 2010 to have pdf documents open in/default to Adobe Acrobat Reader instead of the browser?

Comment: You might want to take a look at an issue already created: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/how-can-i-force-sharepoint-2010-to-open-pdfs-in-the-browser