# Adobe Reader changed it's mind - Now dont open in browser

Tags: pdf

Yeap, I swear I did not change any settings in the IE. About an hour ago I was able to click on a PDF in a document library and IE rendered it find. Now I get a dialog box asking me how do I want to open the item. "Check out & Open", "Open" or "Cancel".

File association looks good. Library settings looks good. Please suggest.

Comment: Is this the same library?  I'm wondering if you had different permissions on the other first one or perhaps it was checked out by another user at the time.

Comment: Did somebody perhaps change the default file open behavior options?

Comment: Is this acting the same on other computers?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Central Admin, you can check about how SharePoint serves up your documents.  It sounds like something happened with the `Browser File Handling` setting in the `Web Application General Setting` ribbon command on the `Manage Web Applications` page.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959917/sharepoint-2010-is-forcing-me-to-save-pdf-when-opening-from-doc-library) question.

**Edit:** please also consider the security considerations brought up in [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/how-can-i-force-sharepoint-2010-to-open-pdfs-in-the-browser?rq=1) before allowing all files to be handled permissively!