# Viewing HTML Pages from a SP List

Tags: document-library

In the SharePoint 2013 environment that I'm developing, I'd like users to be able to view HTML files from a list.
I'm able to a HTML file to the Document Library that I've created, but clicking them only gives the user the option to save the file to the local disk, not to open it. Unlike .txt or .doc files, which can be viewed directly in the browser.

Is there a way to be get the user to view the HTML page in the browser upon clicking it in the list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions that Anders Rask answered here :[How can I force SharePoint 2010 to open PDF's in the browser?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/how-can-i-force-sharepoint-2010-to-open-pdfs-in-the-browser)

but replace

> "application/pdf"

with

> "text/html"

Like so:

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication <your webapp url> 
$webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("text/html")
$webapp.Update()
```

Comment: My thanks, Robert. I was going to test PDF files next, but now that's taken care of as well. :D