# Sharepoint 2016 Open Pdf in adobe

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, pdf

I'm for some reason unable to Open my PDf files in my SharePoint 2016 in Adobe Acrobat or reader x.

I've followed this guide: [SharePoint Search - Force pdf to open in Adobe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142279/sharepoint-search-force-pdf-to-open-in-adobe)

I've also tried this: [SharePoint 2010 open pdf in browser and Adobe Reader X](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120848/sharepoint-2010-open-pdf-in-browser-and-adobe-reader-x)

But it doesn't like I'm able to make it work at all. They open in some look a like word.

This is a screenshot of what it looks like when its open:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things to check and make sure they are configured properly.

1. Disable Adobe reader add-on in browser. Here is how:
   Go to Internet Explorer >> Tools >> Manage Add-ons >> Select "Adobe PDF Reader" and disable it!
2. Change the Web application Browser handling from Permissive to Strict and change the MIME type for PDF.

Please follow the instruction here: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/04/open-pdf-document-browser-sharepoint2010.html

But if you are on SharePoint ONline / Office 365, then u have to wait, and record your voice here" [Open Adobe PDF in client application](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12336546-open-adobe-pdf-in-client-application)

Answer (score 0):

A SOLUTION!
Map the SharePoint  to a drive letter and access it like a NAS.

Open Internet Explorer (not Edge, not Chrome, not Firefox).  If you can’t find IE then ask Cortana to find it.

Go to the Office 365 login.  Tell it to remember you and automatically sign in to avoid sign in over and over.

Login and go to the documents page of the SharePoint site that you want to make into a Mapped Drive.

Click on the “All Documents” with the down arrow the select “View in File Explorer”.  This will needlessly open a new browser tab and, also, open the site in a Windows File Explorer window outside of your browser.

Right click the address and select “copy address”.

Then you can open a new file explorer and start a Map a Network Drive using the copied link as the folder.  Also Choose the reconnect at sign in tick box.

In the future any time it won’t connect likely your signed out in IE open Internet Explorer and sign in again.

Enjoy,
Roy Lamontagne

Comment: That would be for SharePoint online of course.