# Open pdf in place of save as

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, pdf

I've a document library in SharePoint 2010 with some pdf. When i click on a pdf, it proposes save as in place of open.

How to achieve this?

I added this in my master page:

```
 $(function () {
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr("onmousedown");
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");       
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Also see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/how-can-i-force-sharepoint-2010-to-open-pdfs-in-the-browser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make sure the following things in order to open the PDF in browser.

There are two options available

- Browser File Handling should permissive for the web app, you can change it using the Central Admin > Manage web Application> Web Application General Settings. this is kind of security risk.
- Explicitly add PDF to allowable list of MIME types in SharePoint 2010. .Use the below code to add MIME type

  ```
  -#Get web application object   
  $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "web app url"   
  -#List all allowed MIME types for this web application
  $webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes  
  -#Get web application object again
  $webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "web app url"  
  -#Add PDF to allowed MIME type list    
  $webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("application/pdf")
  -#Commit changes
  $webapp.Update()
  ```

http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1187

Also Take a look:

[How to Open PDF files in a web browser -SharePoint 2010](http://curah.microsoft.com/24201/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-a-web-browser-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: If you are using Adobe Acrobat, you will need at least version X of the software. Also, check if your Acrobat to browser integration is working.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend setting it to permissive in production and instead intentional declare it's use (Waqas 2nd bullet).  and as far as opening in the browser itself - that will also depend on the browser and/or application plugins being enabled.

Comment: Are there a way to open pdf in new tab browser?

Comment: you need to add a CEWP and put a code it..check this http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18

Comment: i put the code in master page, like this every pdf on every library are open in a new tab